# SQL Server partition and Run Case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, window-functions

I am trying to get the latest records in **TableB** for an ID .. I tired to rank the top value and then using the results to apply the following conditions to the column called 'Status' in **TableA**:

- If end is null or blank then status = 'Currently Running'
- If the latest record is from the past 48 hours then status = 'Recently Finished'
- If the end was more than 48 hours ago then status = 'not run in more than 48hours'
- else 'no recent activity'

I have attached a [screenshot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73jjc.png).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB](
    [SiteId] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [db_addr] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Start] [datetime] NULL,
    [End] [datetime] NULL,
    [ID] [varchar](50) NULL
) 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([ID], [Status]) VALUES (N'Z1001', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([ID], [Status]) VALUES (N'Z1002', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([ID], [Status]) VALUES (N'Z1003', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[TableA] ([ID], [Status]) VALUES (N'Z3002', N'')

INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'1001', N'E001',   CAST(N'2023-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-05-02T00:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Z1001')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'1001', N'E001', CAST(N'2023-05-02T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-05-02T01:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Z1001')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'1001', N'E001', CAST(N'2023-05-03T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-05-03T01:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Z1001')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'2001', N'B002',     CAST(N'2023-05-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-05-02T00:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Z2001')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'2001', N'B002', CAST(N'2023-05-02T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-05-02T01:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Z2001')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'3001', N'B005', CAST(N'2023-05-02T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), NULL, N'Z3001')
INSERT [dbo].[TableB] ([SiteId], [db_addr], [Start], [End], [ID]) VALUES (N'3002', N'C007', CAST(N'2023-05-10T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2023-05-10T01:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Z3002')
```

I tried to write a SQL Partition statement and then the CASE but it's all going wrong.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT a.ID, Status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.db_addr, b.ID ORDER BY b.[End] DESC) AS rn,
    MAX(b.[End]) OVER (PARTITION BY b.db_addr, b.ID) AS latest_end
  FROM TableA a
  JOIN TableB b ON a.ID = b.ID
)
UPDATE a
SET Status = CASE
  WHEN cte.latest_end IS NULL OR cte.latest_end = '' THEN 'Currently Discharging'
  WHEN cte.rn = 1 AND cte.latest_end >= DATEADD(hour, -48, GETDATE()) THEN 'Discharged recently'
  ELSE 'Not discharged in more than 48hours'
  END
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN cte ON a.ID = cte.ID
WHERE a.ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt, and the expected results for the sample data.

Comment: its possibly a very bad way of trying it ..

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the code, it's unreadable in a comment

Comment: I have added it in. not sure that is the right way to add it in, thank you

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to retrieve the most recent row for each ID, use the window method `ROW_NUMBER()`, and then use `case` clause to get the expected result :

```
with cte as (
  select a.*, b.[End], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by a.ID order by [End]) as rn
  from TableA a
  inner join TableB b on b.ID = a.ID
)
select ID, case when [End] is null then 'Currently Running'
          when [End] >= DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) then 'Recently FInished'
          when [End] < DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) then 'not run in more than 48hours'
          else 'no recent activity' end as Status
from cte
where rn = 1
```

This is the update statement :

```
with cte as (
  select a.*, b.[End], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by a.ID order by [End]) as rn
  from TableA a
  inner join TableB b on b.ID = a.ID
)
UPDATE TableA
set TableA.Status = case when [End] is null then 'Currently Running'
          when [End] >= DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) then 'Recently FInished'
          when [End] < DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) then 'not run in more than 48hours'
          else 'no recent activity' end
from cte c
inner join TableA a on a.ID = c.ID
where rn = 1
```

Result :

```
ID      Status
Z1001   not run in more than 48hours
Z1002   not run in more than 48hours
Z3001   Currently Running
Z3002   Recently FInished
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cOUQDxRC)

Comment: Thank you, but I am expecting a diferent answer: 

ID Status
Z1001 not run in more than 48hours
Z1002 not run in more than 48hours
Z3001 Currently Running
Z3002 Recently FInished

Comment: What you have shared is the result I got, have you checked the demo ?

Comment: Apologies when running in my SQL Server the IDs in TableA was wrong and was returning two values

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Can I please ask how best to change this SQL to an UPDATE SQL so the Status column is updated in TableA

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you need window
functions here. You can get the latest `end` of each `id` from the second table with just a `max`.

We can also avoid the CTE (that your code later joins back to the table), and return the new value directly from a correlated subquery:

```
update a
set status = (
    select 
        case
            when max([End]) is null then 'currently running'
            when max([End]) >= dateadd(day, -2, getdate()) then 'recently finished'
            else 'did not run in more than 48 hours'
        end   
    from tableb b
    where b.id = a.id
)
from tablea a
where a.id is not null
```

Notes:

- the last branch of your `case` (the one that yields *no recent activity*) is unreachable ; the previous branch, *did not run in more than 48 hours*, would match first
- this also updates rows that have no match at all in the second table, and will give them status *did not run in more than 48 hours* - which to me seems consistent with your problem statement and attempt